# How to create 2 dependent dynamic fields in OTRS

Tags: otrs

I need to link 2 different dynamic fields in OTRS. What I have done till now:-

1 Created the ACL in Config file
   2 Changed the customerticketmessage dtl for source binding
   3 Changed the Agentcommonaction dtl

But the result is not reflected in customer webpage

I am now not really getting the way to implement it. Need help for it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of OTRS are you on?
Since OTRS 3.2 the Customer Interface supports ACLs: http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.3/en/html/otrs.html#idp9739616

Also, of course having to achieve your goal via ACLs is not that nice, the best way to go is to create a specific type of drop-down field with multiple levels. This would require some coding, though.